# event beforedrag grid ExtJs 4

Tags: drag-and-drop, grid, extjs4

I want detecte event before drag in Grid when we use 'ptype: gridviewdragdrop' (Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop), like

```
dragZone: {
     onBeforeDrag: function(data, e) {
           //.... instruction;
     }
}
```

Or: how get rows element with grid